# How do I correct a MS Access Run-Time error '2498' in Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I am trying to write a code that will print out my current form for the current record. This is what I am using:

```
Private Sub PrintCommand_Click()
Dim myform As Form
Dim pageno As Long
pageno = Me.CurrentRecord
Set myform = Screen.ActiveForm
DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, myform.Name, True
DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, pageno, pageno, , 1
DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, myform.Name, False
End Sub
```

When I dimension "pageno" as an integer, it gives me an overflow error for some of my records that exceed 65000. So, I dimensioned it as a long data type, but then I receive the following error:
Run-time error '2498': An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments."

I also tried making "pageno" a variant data type, and I received the same 2498 error message. Any suggestions on either a way to fix this or another work around for printing my form for the current record?

Update: This works and accomplishes what I was going for...

```
Private Sub PrintCommand_Click()
'Print out the current record
Me.Filter = "[Quote Number] = " & QuoteNumberEntry.Value
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.PrintOut
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Since `Copies` *defaults* to `1`, have you considered just deleting everything after the second `, pageno`?  It might be the blank value for `PrintQuality` that causes the issue - you could also try `acHigh`, the default value, and see if that works

Comment: @Chronocidal I tried the following options for the DoCmd.Printout line of code and unfortunately they were unsuccessful:
DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, pageno, pageno
DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, pageno, pageno, acHigh, 1, 1

Comment: "Workaround" is to use appropriate vehicle for printing - a report.

Comment: AFAIK, a record does not equate to a page. A page is determined when number of records exceeds length of paper that printer driver is defaulting to. Apply filter to form so only the 1 record is retrieved.

Comment: @June7 Thank you, I will try a filter. I am aware that a report is a more appropriate method for printing, but I am upgrading a pre-existing file that I did not create, and I would like to continue using the form if possible.

Comment: Why? User need not be aware that a report is printing.

Comment: @June7 I also don't want to have to recreate the report to look like the form. Is there a way to quickly create a report that looks identical to the form?

Comment: Open the form > File > SaveObjectAs > provide name and select Report. Doubt result will be identical to form.